# Write to file and prevent formating

Tags: fortran

I write to a file rows of (x,y) coordinates which are of real type. I do it in this way:

```
open(UNIT=23,FILE="plotdata.txt")
do while(...)
    write(23, *) x," ", y
enddo  
close(23)
```

But when I open the file I see a lot of extra space around numbers. But what I want is just a number, a space and the second number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try to use this format:

```
write(23, fmt="(F0.2, A1, F0.2)") x, " ", y
```

That will give you the numbers without surrounding spaces. The 2 is the number of digits behind the dot.